# Autolaunched (record-created trigger) flow doesn't trigger when record is created by a screen flow embedded in an Experience Builder site

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, experience-builder-page, recordtriggeredflow

We use Autolaunched Flows that trigger on record creation in our org to send email notifications to users (specifically Public Groups of users). One such Autolaunched Flow is not triggering when a record is created, but only under specific circumstances. The flow, `Notification: Scholarship Application Created` is:

- set to trigger whenever a `Scholarship__c` record is created,
- has no entry condition requirements, and
- is optimized for "Actions and Related Records"

We are creating a site using Experience Builder where applicants can create scholarship applications. To do this, applicants use a Screen Flow, `Scholarship Application`, which is embedded in the Experience Builder site. The screen flow collects user input and creates `Scholarship__c` records.

Our expectation is that the autolaunched `Notification: Scholarship Application Created` flow will trigger when a `Scholarship__c` record is created by the `Scholarship Application` screen flow. In reality:

- The `Notification: Scholarship Application Created` flow triggers successfully when a `Scholarship__c` record is **created manually**.
- The `Notification: Scholarship Application Created` flow triggers successfully when a `Scholarship__c` record is created by the `Scholarship Application` flow **in debug mode**.
- The `Notification: Scholarship Application Created` flow **does not trigger** when a `Scholarship__c` record is created by the `Scholarship Application` when the `Scholarship Application` flow is accessed through the **Experience Builder** site.

It is not clear to us what is causing the Autolaunched Flow not to trigger only when a `Scholarship__c` record is created through the embedded screen flow in the experience cloud site.

Comment: I've actually found the solution to this question, but don't have enough reputation to answer my own question. It turns out that Activating the Experience Builder site (it was previously in Preview mode) fixes the issue. Scholarship__c records created by the Scholarship Application screen flow embedded in the Experience Builder site now trigger the Notification: Scholarship Application Created flow. I'm not sure WHY this change had an affect. Any advice or thoughts would be greatly appreciated!